# Unable to connect Db2 using protractor

Tags: typescript, db2

While trying to connect to a remote DB2 database I am getting following exception

> SQL30081N A communication error has been detected.
>
> > Communication protocol being used 'TCP/IP'. Communication API being used 'SOCKETS'. Location where error was detected "192.168.1.200'.
> >     Communication function detecting the error 'SelectForConnectTimeout'.
> >     Protocol specific error code '0','*','*'. SQLSTATE=08001

i am using following connection string

```
let conn= await ibmdb.open("Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2V11};DATABASE=DBInstance;UID=username;PWD=password;HOSTNAME=hostname;port=446;");
result = await conn.query(sql_Query);
```

Comment: Is the reported IP address that of the database host? Why is it port 446? The standard for Db2 on Linux / Windows is 5000.

Comment: Configuration question ( not programming).  This is frequently asked question.  Follow basic troubleshooting advice in  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164785

Comment: @data_henrik I am using '60030' port number , which can be able to connect it from data studio manually. Do we need any extra settings i am using ibmdb depandancy in package.json

Comment: Your provided code says `port=446`.

Comment: No, I am using 60030 and mistakenly provided 446 port.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Db2 manual below, it is typically outside the Db2 software:

**Protocol-specific error codes for the SQL30081N message**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/r0052008.html

---

*The cause of the SQL30081N message is typically outside the Db2 software and actual error codes are protocol-specific.*

---

And the message tells that the issue was detected at **"192.168.1.200"**.
Generally speaking, the IP address **"192.168.1.200"** may be a virtual IP which can be assigned to other devices.  So it is suggested to try a real IP address instead to see if the problem persists or not.

Hope this helps.